# is this a right query to get the info I need

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT

table1.id

From 
table1
Join 
table2
ON 
table1.id = table2.id 

WHERE 
table1.`date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE();
```

join table record set is

```
id  customer    date
1   john        2011-01-01
2   john1       2011-02-02
3   john2       2011-03-03
4   john3       2011-04-04
5   john4       2011-05-05
6   john5       2011-06-06
7   john6       2011-07-07
8   john7       2011-08-08
9   john8       2011-09-09
10  john9       2011-10-10
11  john10      2011-10-11
```

I was wondering if this is the right where clause to find if the customer that has a date over 30 days due.

Comment: What's the point of the join?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE 
table1.`date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE() ;
```

will give you all rows with `date` between today and one month ago. If that's what you want, keep the query.

If you want all rows with `date` older than one month ago, use this:

```
WHERE 
table1.`date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ;
```

or this (not exactly the same results with previous):

```
WHERE 
table1.`date` < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY ;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the importance of table2 in your SQL so perhaps this will do ...

```
select id, customer, date
  from table1
 where datediff(curdate(), date) > 30
```

Comment: +1 I think his will return nothing because of the join, but besides that, it would return matches in the last 30 days.

Comment: The problem with writing the condition with `DATEDIFF()` is that an index of `date` can't be used. (It should be but MySQL cannot understand/transform this).

Comment: "I don't see the importance of table2" -- existential qualification, perhaps? i.e. only include in results if a row exists in table2 with the same id value, a.k.a. semijoin.